# Replace function is doesnt work on pandas filtered dataframe, How can I improve that

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

`train_data[(train_df['Survived']==1)&(train_df['Pclass']==1)&(train_df['Sex']=='female')]['Age'].replace(38,34.9, inplace=True)`

When I used this code DataFrame doesn't change. I cant understand why.

`train_data.isnull().sum()` this code still imprinted NaN values in this filtered section.

Comment: Basic, but still: did you assing your filtered df? DF_small =DF[DF['survived'] == .....

Comment: No, I created 12 filters this way and I want them to make changes on the actual dataframe.

`train_data[(train_df['Survived']==1)&(train_df['Pclass']==1)&(train_df['Sex']=='female')]['Age'].replace(np.nan,34.9, inplace=True)
train_data[(train_df['Survived']==0)&(train_df['Pclass']==1)&(train_df['Sex']=='female')]['Age'].replace(np.nan,25.6, inplace=True)`
.
.
.

Comment: I Suggest you create the train_data_small. Then you can add each condition one by one and see when/if the system fails.

Comment: `inplace=True` is frowned upon, maybe you should let it go.

Comment: I have already used "inplace=True"

Comment: yes, `inplace=True` is frowned upon, maybe you should let it go.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was improved by firstly using a small array and then appending them in order.
This solution has index problem it solved with;

I will write def for this code.

````
newage = pd.DataFrame([])
newage = pd.concat((newage,a),axis=0,ignore_index=False,sort=True)
newage = pd.concat((newage,b),axis=0,ignore_index=False,sort=True)
newage = pd.concat((newage,c),axis=0,ignore_index=False,sort=True)
newage = pd.concat((newage,d),axis=0,ignore_index=False,sort=True)
newage = pd.concat((newage,e),axis=0,ignore_index=False,sort=True)
newage = pd.concat((newage,f),axis=0,ignore_index=False,sort=True)
newage = pd.concat((newage,g),axis=0,ignore_index=False,sort=True)
newage = pd.concat((newage,h),axis=0,ignore_index=False,sort=True)
newage = pd.concat((newage,j),axis=0,ignore_index=False,sort=True)
newage = pd.concat((newage,k),axis=0,ignore_index=False,sort=True)
newage = pd.concat((newage,l),axis=0,ignore_index=False,sort=True)
newage = pd.concat((newage,m),axis=0,ignore_index=False,sort=True)
newage

train_data["newage"] = newage
train_data.head(15)```
````